# Should I use single or double quotes in Cypher queries?

Tags: cypher, graph-databases, memgraphdb

Is it better to use `'` or `"` when I need to return the text? I have the following return statement:

*Please don't forget to submit your ID.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to quotes, a simple rule is to use whichever provides the fewest escaped characters in the string. If escaped characters are not needed, or their number is the same for single and double quotes, then single quotes should be favored.

In your case since you have a `'` character in text you have two possible options. First one with escape character `\`

```
RETURN 'Please don\'t forget to submit your ID.'
```

and second one without.

```
RETURN "Please don't forget to submit your ID."
```

The end result is the same.